# Is it possible to setCellValue directly without the need of a multidimentional array?

Tags: php, xml, multidimensional-array, phpexcel

I currently started working on a script that had already been done. It works great, but it takes way too long and I believe I know the cause but I have had no success in improving it.

The case is as follows, the script reads a XML file with a lot of info regarding temperatures, all of which are inside the various `<Previsao>` tags inside the xml.

```
$l = 3;

$q = $CON->Query("SELECT 
                            cod_cidade, 
                            cidade, 
                            cidcompleta 
                      FROM 
                            listabrasil 
                      WHERE 
                            cidade LIKE '%Aj%' 
                      ORDER BY 
                            cidade ASC");

    while ($x = $CON->Fetch ($q))
    {
        $XML = simplexml_load_file('http://ws.somarmeteorologia.com.br/previsao.php?Cidade='.$x['cidade'].'&DiasPrevisao=15');
        print $x['cidade']."\n";    
        foreach ($XML->Previsao as $P)
        {   
            $Previsao[$x['cidade']]['data'][] = (string)$P->Data;
            $Previsao[$x['cidade']]['tmin'][] = (float) $P->Tmin;
            $Previsao[$x['cidade']]['tmax'][] = (float) $P->Tmax;
            $Previsao[$x['cidade']]['prec'][] = (float) $P->Prec;
            $Previsao[$x['cidade']]['velvento'][] = (float) $P->VelVento;
            $Previsao[$x['cidade']]['dirvento'][] = (string)$P->DirVento;
        }
    }

    foreach ($Previsao as $Cid => $Dados) 
    {
        $col = 1;
        for($dias = 0; $dias < 15 ; $dias++)
        {
            $PlanilhaBloomberg->setCellValue($colunas[$col+0].'2', $Dados['data'][$dias]);
            $PlanilhaBloomberg->setCellValue($colunas[$col+0].$l, $Dados['tmin'][$dias].'C');
            $PlanilhaBloomberg->setCellValue($colunas[$col+1].$l, $Dados['tmax'][$dias].'C');
            $PlanilhaBloomberg->setCellValue($colunas[$col+2].$l, $Dados['prec'][$dias].'mm');
            $PlanilhaBloomberg->setCellValue($colunas[$col+3].$l, $Dados['velvento'][$dias].'km/h');
            $PlanilhaBloomberg->setCellValue($colunas[$col+4].$l, $Dados['dirvento'][$dias]);

            print $Dados['data'][$dias]."\n";
            print $Dados['tmin'][$dias]."\n";
            print $Dados['tmax'][$dias]."\n";
            print $Dados['prec'][$dias]."\n";
            print $Dados['velcento'][$dias]."\n";
            print $Dados['dirvento'][$dias]."\n";

            $col = $col + 5;
        }
        $l++;
    }
```

Don't worry about the setCellValue, it's just from the PHPExcel library. So, from what I could gather, it's taking so long to execute due to obviously the large amount of data that it's gathering from the XML, but also because it keeps filling the multidimensional array $Previsao ... What I am hoping to achieve (with no success, might I add) is to fill the setCellValue directly, without the need for a multidimensional array. Do you guys think it's possible, if it is, would this reduce the exec_time for the script?

Thank you all in advance for the help, and also please forgive me if this question is too focused, not sure if this could cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

PHPExcel usually does take a long time to setCellValues. Their might be an optimal solution to better of your code but i don't think it would make an excessive difference when it comes to runtime. Try to setPreCalculateFormulas(False) before saving your file so that PHPExcel doesn't calculate values on save. That might save some time. Second of all, assuming $PlanilhaBloomberg is $object->getActiveSheet(), you can call it as such

```
        $PlanilhaBloomberg->setCellValue($colunas[$col+0].'2', $Dados['data'][$dias]);
                          ->setCellValue($colunas[$col+0].$l, $Dados['tmin'][$dias].'C');
                          ->setCellValue($colunas[$col+1].$l, $Dados['tmax'][$dias].'C');
                          ->setCellValue($colunas[$col+2].$l, $Dados['prec'][$dias].'mm');
                          ->setCellValue($colunas[$col+3].$l, $Dados['velvento'][$dias].'km/h');
                          ->setCellValue($colunas[$col+4].$l, $Dados['dirvento'][$dias]);
```

That might help.

Comment: Anyway wait for the Baker. He might be able to help better. Hope i did.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are iterating over the database result, iterating over the xml for each database result, in order to build a big array in memory; then iterating over that array to build the Excel sheet.... surely it should be possible to avoid building the big array; arrays are memory expensive, and a lot of time overhead is spent in allocating the memory for that array as well.

It should be possible too populate the Excel directly from the XML loop, avoiding the entire array building (which saves memory and memory allocation time) and saves an entire loop as well.

It's really just a case of identifying which cell needs populating from which XML value; but I can't envisage the array structure to work that out